# NgFor iterator over Observable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following Map in a Service:

```
   private slotlist: Map<number, SlotItem>;
```

SlotItem is a class. I give the slotlist back from the service with:

```
getSlotItems(): Observable<ObservedValueOf<Map<number, SlotItem>>>
```

Two things are not clear:

1. How do I subscribe to the slotitems

   this.slotitems = this.BService.getSlotItems();

   this.slotitems.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
2. How do I iterate with ngfor over the items

I tried

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of slotitems">
```

but I get the erro that slotitems it not assignable to NgIterable.

**Changes from the below help:**

If I change

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of slotitems | async">
```

I get an error in the html if I write

```
          <ion-icon *ngIf="item.value.active"
 [name]="item.value.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
```

The fields "active" and "icon" are member in the slotitem class.

```
ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.value is undefined"
```

At the moment the slotitems list is set fix in the service. Later this comes from a database

```
this.slotlist.set(1, new SlotItem( 1, true,  'None', 'None', 'None' ));
```

If I add the safe traversal operator it works but not for the "div"

```
      <div *ngIf="!item?.value?.active" style="color:darkgray">
        <{{item.value.title}}>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of slotitems">
```

Use:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of slotitems | async | keyvalue">
```

The [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) subscribes and unsubscribes to your observable as needed, and returns the latest value of the observable every time a new one is emitted.

This also means you don't need to subscribe to the observable yourself anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access the element of the class: "item.value.id" does not work.

Comment: Could you update your question showing where you try to access `item.value.id`?

Comment: I have done it. I am a little bit more confused now. The other answers above said that I should use subscribe.

Comment: So `<ion-icon>` is in between `<ion-item>` and `</ion-item>`? If so, may it be your `item` doesn't have a `value` field? If that's the case, you can use the safe traversal operator `?.` like this: `item?.value?.active`

Comment: Question extended. I get always TypeError.

Comment: Updated, you need `keyvalue` because your `item` is a Map entry

Answer (score 0):

I switched to BehaviorSubject and CArray. It works fine now

In the service I write

```
private slotlist: Array<SlotItem>;
private behSlotData: BehaviorSubject<SlotItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject<SlotItem[]>([]);

getSlotItems(): Observable<SlotItem[]>
```

In the component

```
  public slotitems: Observable<SlotItem[]>;
...
  this.slotitems = this.btClassic.getSlotItems();
```

and now in the html I access the elements with

```
*ngFor="let item of slotitems | async"
```

and the member access is direct because of the async

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="item.active" [name]="item.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.To subscribe to an observable do as below

```
this.BService.getSlotItems().subscribe(data=>{
     this.slotitems = data.values();
})
```

data.values() will return all the values from map as iteratable

2. After adding above *ngFor will work fine if its not working add async pipe like below

*ngFor="let item of slotitems | async"

then use item.id and item.active directly

which will inform slotitems will be coming from the service or it will be loaded dynamically